# How to allow the user to place their own pin google maps api V2 with android sdk(JAVA)

Tags: java, android, sdk, google-maps-api-2

How to allow the user to place or Drag a custom marker(Eg.Image) anywhere on google maps?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make your user able to set a custom location in your Map, you can achieve it by doing the following:

1. Your activity / fragment has to implement the `OnMapClickListener`  interface
2. Set your map listener like this: `myMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);`
3. Implement `public void onMapClick(LatLng point)` which is the method you have to implement in step 1.
4. Get the LatLong position from this method and place your marker in that point.

Like this:

```
MarkerOptions options=new MarkerOptions().snippet(getString(R.string.snippet))
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mymarker))
        .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f);
options.position(point);
myMap.addMarker(options);
```

Comment: Thanks, how might I add text to one of these markers?

Comment: The `snippet` method add a text when you click on your marker.